# Audio filter for Android

Tags: android, filter

I needed a audio filter in android.Is google developed any filter(low, high or band pass) for android.If yes so please give some link or information about that or if not so please tell me alternative way to how to create a filter in android or how to used the filter of native languages like C/C++ in android through ndk.
                  Sorry for this question, I have already searched in google and not find any answer. So i am asking this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the AudioEffect API for playback, which includes e.g. an equalizer. But I'm not 100% sure if all equalizer implementations support modifying individual frequency bands, or if some just provide a bunch of presets (pop, rock, etc) that you can switch between. The number of frequency bands might also differ between different implementations.

For recordings there's a new API in Android 4.1 (Jellybean) which allows you to add what they call pre-processing effects. There's no kind of equalizer available by default though; just an echo canceller, and automatic gain controller, and a noise reducer.

Another possibility would be for you to do all the processing yourself in your app (either in the Java code or in one of your native libraries). Run your C filter implementations on a PCM stream and then play it through OpenSL ES, or pass the processed stream up to Java through JNI and play it through an AudioTrack. With this approach, if you need to work with compressed streams you'll have to bundle the necessary codecs with your app and do the encoding/decoding yourself.

Comment: Thankyou Michael but i have a problem to using echo canceller, noise reducer, noise suppressor and other class of AudioEffect API because Android not give more information about them and also there is no sample example in google. If u have any information about them please share it.And also share how used them.

Comment: "To attach the `AcousticEchoCanceler` to a particular `AudioRecord`, specify the audio session ID of this `AudioRecord` when creating the `AcousticEchoCanceler`. The audio session is retrieved by calling `getAudioSessionId()` on the `AudioRecord` instance."     And similarly for the other effects. See e.g.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AcousticEchoCanceler.html

Comment: u have any working example for this because it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't have any code examples. Keep in mind though that those pre-processing effects are only supported from API level 16 (Jellybean) and later. Also, even with the correct API level / Android version you should use the isAvailable method to see if your device supports the effect.